# Text is misaligned in PDF with fillable field only in Safari

Tags: safari, pdflib

I have a PDF that is generated with PDFlib that has fillable fields. They work as expected on Chrome, FF, Edge, IE, but not on Safari.

We have no Macs at work, so I'm looking at this using SauceLabs with OSX El Capitan, Safari 9.3 on 1376x1032 resolution.

When I fill out the fillable field on a form such as `https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdf-on-the-web-server/starter-webform/php-starter-webform/` in-browser (again, Safari only), when you click outside the fillable field, the text moves up a couple of pixels. Click to edit again and it regains its original position. Click outside and it moves up again.

Is this an unavoidable Safari bug or is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening (currently reading the PDFlib documentation, and I have seen nothing that remotely mentions this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They work as expected on Chrome, FF, Edge, IE, but not on Safari.

please get in mind, all browsers have in the moment only limited PDF viewing support. (they are getting better and better with each versions, but they are not yet perfect)

Please use for viewing PDF files the PDF reference product Adobe Acrobat (Reader). Also other PDF viewers like the Apple Preview are not feature complete and might not display everything correct.

When it display correctly in Adobe Acrobat Reader, you know the PDF is fine and it's a bug in the viewer you use.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. I thought maybe there was a PDFlib option that would make sure things aren't moved around, but there isn't after all.